# Find strings only optionally containing a specific char at the end

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to find strings that have no `。` char in them, with an optional occurrence of this character at the end of the string.

I search some tips, like that, but didn't solve my problem.

```
^(?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*\.\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$
(?!\.) - don't allow . at start
(?!.*\.\.) - don't allow 2 consecutive dots
(?!.*\.$) - don't allow . at end
```

I tried to use

```
str_l  = ["aaa。bbb。","aaa。","aaa"]
for str1 in str_l:
  res1 = re.search(r'(.*?!。*$)', str1) #if 。not in string, return True
  res2 = re.search(r'(?<!(。)。$)',str1) # if 。 only appear at the end of string, return True, but not solved
  print(res1,res2)
```

I want to combine `res1` and `res2` to one regex, and the string results like `False, True, True`.

Comment: All you need `if not str1.endswith('。'):`. In regex, `re.search(r'$(?<!。)', str1)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Genius and thanks lot! but actually I want to combine with this one: r'(.*!。.*$)'   there is no period in this string

Comment: I want find those string that dont have peroid or period only appear at the end of string...

Comment: You mean you need to return *True* / string if the string contains no `。` but can optionally have a `。` at the end?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  yes, and at the same time return False if 。in the middle of string

Comment: Can you please edit the question to actually ask this? And please state the expected result.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew hello, I have correct it!

Comment: See https://ideone.com/EnxvD1

Comment: What about `"I have 1,000.00 dollars in my bank account!"? Or "Wait... is that correct?" and "Hello, my name is J. J. Abrahams."

Comment: @Grismar because there all have . in the middle of string, so all return false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
str_l  = ["aaa。bbb。","aaa。","aaa"]
for str1 in str_l:
  print(str1, '=>', bool(re.search(r'^[^。]*。?$', str1)))
```

Output:

```
# => aaa。bbb。 => False
aaa。 => True
aaa => True
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EnxvD1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^。]*` - zero or more chars other than the dot
- `。?` - an optional dot
- `$` -  at the end of string.

To obtain the valid strings from the list using this regex, you can use

```py
rx = re.compile(r'^[^。]*。?$')
print( list(filter(rx.search, str_l)) )
# => ['aaa。', 'aaa']
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the following code.

```py
import re

p = re.compile("^(?:(?!。).)*(。$)?(?!.*。).*$")

l = [
    "aaa。bbb。",
    "aaa bbb。",  # matches because only at end
    "aaa。bbb",
    "。aaa bbb",
    "aaa bbb",  # matches because none found
]

print([s for s in l if p.match(s)])
```

Which results in:

```
['aaa bbb。', 'aaa bbb']
```

The full explanation can be found [here at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PWn8fi/1).

The only advantage to this matching expression over the much more terse `^[^。]*。?$` is that it can be used with strings in addition to a given character. So, say you need to match strings that may end with "foo" but it shall not appear earlier in the string. Then you could use `^(?:(?!foo).)*(foo$)?(?!.*foo).*$`.

However, it is about 60% slower. You can see the test and results here:

```py
import re
import timeit

a = re.compile("^(?:(?!。).)*(。$)?(?!.*。).*$")
b = re.compile("^[^。]*。?$")

l = [
    "aaa。bbb。",
    "aaa bbb。",  # matches because only at end
    "aaa。bbb",
    "。aaa bbb",
    "aaa bbb",  # matches because none found
]

print(
    timeit.timeit(
        "matches = [s for s in l if a.match(s)]",
        setup="from __main__ import (l, a)",
    )
)

print(
    timeit.timeit(
        "matches = [s for s in l if b.match(s)]",
        setup="from __main__ import (l, b)",
    )
)
```

Which gives:

```
2.6208932230000004
1.6510743480000003
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach can be splitting on `。`

If you use split and the is  `。` at the end of the string, the last item in the list will be empty.

If it does not occur, the list size is 1.

```
str_l = ["aaa。bbb。", "aaa。", "aaa", "。", "。  ", "。。"]

for str1 in str_l:
    lst = str1.split(r"。")
    nr = len(lst)
    print(f"'{str1}' -> {nr == 1 or nr == 2 and lst[1] == ''}")
```

Output

```
'aaa。bbb。' -> False
'aaa。' -> True
'aaa' -> True
'。' -> True
'。  ' -> False
'。。' -> False
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/x6rMpS).